# How to hide penultimate span’s :after selector in a list of span

Tags: css, css-selectors

I struggle with CSS task. I am trying to hide the before last span’s a:after selector. Here is my code:

```
<span class="navigation_page">
     <span><a><span></span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span></span></a></span>
     ...
     <span>**<a>**<span></span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span></span></a></span>
</span>
```

The before last span has no class and every link (a) has selector :after.

I figured out this solution nevertheless it does not work.

```
.navigation_page span:last-child(-1) a:after {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Try `.navigation_page :nth-last-child(2) a:after` to address the second-to-last span.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in my comment here's an example to address the `a` in question.

```css
.navigation_page span:nth-last-child(2) a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="navigation_page">
     <span><a><span>First</span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span></span></a></span>
     ...
     <span><a><span>Second-to-last</span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span>Last</span></a></span>
</span>
```

Here is a more sophisticated example using `:after` selectors. Each link is appended with `[link]` (first CSS rule) and the targeted `:after` of the second-to-last link is not displayed.

```css
.navigation_page span a:after {
  content: '[link]';
}
.navigation_page span:nth-last-child(2) a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="navigation_page">
     <span><a><span>First</span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span></span></a></span>
     ...
     <span><a><span>Second-to-last</span></a></span>
     <span class="navigation-pipe"><a><span>Last</span></a></span>
</span>
```